# How does a nodejs app become aware a new primary mongodb was elected within a replica set?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, replication

I read a little about mongodb replication.  I want to set up mongodb replication with two servers in two different data centers so that it offers greater availability to the NodeJS apps that connect to it.  Let's say I have the primary mongodb instance in Newark, New Jersey, USA with IP `111.111.111.111` and the secondary mongo db instance in Toronto, Ontario, Canada with IP `222.222.222.222`.  From what I understand, if `111.111.111.111` experiences a failure, then `222.222.222.222` will elect itself as primary.

What I don't understand is how I should configure the database connections of my NodeJS apps to communicate with any of the mongodb instances.  I don't understand how my NodeJS app will successfully transmit data to the database in the event of network outages with the data centers of `111.111.111.111` or `222.222.222.222`.  For example, consider the following scenario:

- In my NodeJS app, my `.env` file has a database connection string with a `DB_HOST=111.111.111.111`.
- The data center at `111.111.111.111` experience network outage.
- The NodeJS app can not reach `111.111.111.111` and receives a `network timeout` error.
- The mongodb instance at `222.222.222.222` elects itself as primary database.
- The NodeJS app is not aware of the existence of `222.222.222.222`

So how will my NodeJS app know to switch over to `222.222.222.222` ?  Should my NodeJS app connect to a load balancer, and the load balancer connects to each mongodb instance of the replica set?   Or does my NodeJS app need to have an array of failover mongodb connections and systematically try each one until success occurs?  Or do I build some kind of Websocket/MQTT broker server that communicates the health of each mongodb instance to my nodejs app so that my nodejs app knows which instance to connect to prior to each transmission?

How do I get my NodeJS app to successfully transmit data to mongodb when the primary has failed?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-dns-seedlist

Comment: thanks, will try that out!